# SQL Server 2005: How to join table rows only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I think I've seen answers for similar questions for MySQL, but I'm struggling to find an answer applicable to SQL Server 2005.

So I have a table like this:

```
| ID | RelationalID | Year
----------------------------
| 1  | A            | 2014
| 2  | A            | 2014
| 3  | B            | 2014
| 4  | A            | 2015
| 5  | B            | 2015
```

And I'd like a result like this when I join the same table where RelationID matches but the year is different:

```
| 2014_ID | 2015_ID | RelationalID |
------------------------------------
| 1       | 4       | A            |
| 2       | NULL    | A            |
| 3       | 5       | B            |
```

But a standard JOIN ends up getting duplicate matches:

```
| 2014_ID | 2015_ID | RelationalID |
------------------------------------
| 1       | 4       | A            |
| 2       | 4       | A            |
| 3       | 5       | B            |
```

Is there a way to join two tables where the matches from the right table are joined only once in SQL Server 2005?

I tried this query with no success:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM myTable) AS t ON t.RelationalID = myTable.RelationalID 
WHERE myTable.Year = 2014 and t.Year = 2015
```

Comment: Can you add the query that did not work?

Comment: Example non-working query would be: SELECT * FROM myTable LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM myTable) AS t ON t.RelationalID = myTable.RelationalID WHERE myTable.Year = 2014 and t.Year = 2015

Comment: Can you explain why {2,4,A} is not a valid output but {1,4,A} is?

Comment: Basically its not possible unless you want to go for a really complicated query. So the next question is why do you want the data in the form that you want to see it?

Comment: @Anon {2,4,A} is not valid because 2015_ID 4 has already been matched in the set {1,4,A}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result based on ROW_NUMBERs, but you need a rule how to assign them, I assumed it's based on the Id.

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT Id,
        RelationalId,
        year,
        row_number() 
        over (partition by RelationalId, year
              order by Id) as rn
FROM [YourTable] 
)
select t1.id as Id_2014,t2.id as Id_2015, t1.RelationalId
from cte as t1 left join cte as t2
on t1.RelationalId = t2.RelationalId
and t1.rn = t2.rn
and t2.year = 2015 
where t1.Year = 2014
```

This is based on TMNT2014's [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6300/37)

Comment: The CTE methods with partitioning seem to do the trick. This method gets a few more results than @Kevin Cook's answer so I've marked this as the accepted answer. I'm not familiar with PARTITION, so this is very helpful. Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Below Sql would give you the result you are looking for but as I said before complexity would depend on the original set of data you have in your table. Here is the SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6300/24  - Good Luck!

```
;WITH CTE_Union AS
(SELECT 

    a.Id AS Id2014,
    NULL AS Id2015,
    a.RelationalId
  FROM [YourTable] a
  WHERE a.Year = 2014 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    NULL AS Id2014,
    b.Id AS Id2015,
    b.RelationalId
  FROM [YourTable] b
  WHERE b.Year = 2015)
SELECT Distinct CASE WHEN Id2014 IS NULL THEN (SELECT MIN(Id2014) FROM CTE_Union C WHERE    C.RelationalId =M.RelationalId) ELSE Id2014 END AS ID2014 , 
CASE WHEN Id2015 IS NULL AND Id2014 =  (SELECT MIN(Id2014) FROM CTE_Union C2 WHERE      C2.RelationalId =M.RelationalId) THEN (SELECT MIN(Id2015) FROM CTE_Union C WHERE       C.RelationalId =M.RelationalId) ELSE Id2015 END
,RelationalID
FROM CTE_Union M
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
 (
    ID INT,
    RelationalID VARCHAR(10),
    [Year] INT
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
( 1 ,'A', 2014),
( 2 ,'A', 2014),
( 3 ,'B', 2014),
( 4 ,'A', 2015),
( 5 ,'B', 2015)

;WITH TEST AS
(
    SELECT 
        a.Id AS Id2014,
        NULL AS Id2015,
        a.RelationalId,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RelationalId ORDER BY ID) Ranked
    FROM @MyTable a
    WHERE a.Year = 2014 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        NULL AS Id2014,
        b.Id AS Id2015,
        b.RelationalId,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RelationalId ORDER BY ID) Ranked
    FROM @MyTable b
    WHERE b.Year = 2015
)
SELECT
    t1.Id2014,
    t2.Id2015,
    t1.RelationalID
FROM TEST t1
LEFT JOIN TEST t2
    ON t1.Ranked = t2.Ranked
    AND t1.RelationalID = t2.RelationalID
    AND t2.Id2015 IS NOT NULL
WHERE t1.Id2014 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.Id2014
```

I used a union and then ranked each side by relational id and left joined them.
Here is the output:

```
Id2014  Id2015  RelationalID
1   4   A
2   NULL    A
3   5   B
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to solve this but below shows an example of utilizing "Derived Tables" in a query.

```
SELECT
  q1.Id AS [2014_Id],
  q2.Id AS [2015_Id],
  q1.RelationalId
FROM (SELECT 
        MAX(a.Id) AS Id,
        a.RelationalId
      FROM [table] a
      WHERE a.Year = 2014
      GROUP BY 
        a.RelationalId) q1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              MAX(b.Id) AS Id,
              b.RelationalId
            FROM [table] b
            WHERE b.Year = 2015
            GROUP BY 
                b.RelationalId) q2 
  ON q2.RelationalId = q1.RelationalId
```

Comment: This won't work- it can still match the same row from the right table multiple times even if it's getting distinct rows.

Comment: So which Id would you want in that scenario.  the First or the last? or if there were 3 the one in the middle?  Does it matter?

Comment: @spongessuck Modified the answer.  perhaps this is what your looking for